# Application works fine on simulator but crashes on devise

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My application work fine on simulator, but when I run it on devise, it works the first time and then it crashes. The application crashes with this code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userId, @"userID", pseudoField.text, @"pseudo", birthdateField.text,@"birthdate",sex,@"sex",countryField.text,@"country",cityField.text,@"city",mail,@"mail",token,@"token",tokenExp,@"token", tokenExp,@"tokenEpr", altitude,@"altitude",longitude,@"longitude",pictureLink,@"pic", nil];
```

If I delete 
`altitude,@"altitude",longitude,@"longitude",pictureLink,@"pic" ,` 
it works fine, if I let one of them, this clashes.
This is the code of the 3 variables.

In .h

```
    NSString *altitude;
    NSString *longitude;
    NSString *pictureLink;
    @property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *pictureLink;
    @property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *altitude;
    @property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *longitude;
in .m

    - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
     altitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
     longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude];

    }

    -(IBAction) validate:(id)sender
    {
    if([pseudoField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [birthdateField.text isEqualToString:@""] ||
           [countryField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [cityField.text isEqualToString:@""])

        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Veuillez remplir tout les champs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
            [alert show];


        }
        else
        {

        if (mail == nil || mail==NULL)
        {
            mail=@"NULL";
        }

        if (token == nil || token==NULL)
        {
            token=@"NULL";
        }

        if (tokenExp == nil || tokenExp==NULL)
        {
            tokenExp=@"NULL";
        }


        if (altitude == nil || altitude==NULL)
        {
            altitude=@"NULL";
        }

        if (longitude == nil || longitude==NULL)
        {
            longitude=@"NULL";
        }

            picActivity.hidden=NO;
            [picActivity startAnimating];



            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480)); 
            [userImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,480)];
            UIImage *m = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            NSData* mageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(m, 0.5); 
            NSString *hash;
            hash=[self md5:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userId]];

            NSString * myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.info/upimage.php?n=%@",hash];  
            NSLog(@"url string %@ ",myURLString);
            NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];

            NSString * myPictureUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.info/uploads/%@.jpg",hash];
            [self setPictureLink:myPictureUrl];

            ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
            // Upload a file on disk
            [request setData:mageData withFileName:@"photo.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"file"];
            [request setDelegate:self];
            request.didFinishSelector = @selector(resultUpload:);
            request.didFailSelector = @selector(imageError:);

            [request startAsynchronous];
    }
    }

    -(void)resultUpload :(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        picActivity.hidden=YES;
        [picActivity stopAnimating];
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"seccess upload image , result : %@",responseString);
        if([responseString isEqualToString:@"ok"])
        {
           NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userId, @"userID", pseudoField.text, @"pseudo", birthdateField.text,@"birthdate",sex,@"sex",countryField.text,@"country",cityField.text,@"city",mail,@"mail",token,@"token",tokenExp,@"token", tokenExp,@"tokenEpr", altitude,@"altitude",longitude,@"longitude",pictureLink,@"pic", nil];


     //  THIS IT WORK FINE     NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userId, @"userID", pseudoField.text, @"pseudo", birthdateField.text,@"birthdate",sex,@"sex",countryField.text,@"country",cityField.text,@"city",mail,@"mail",token,@"token",tokenExp,@"token", tokenExp,@"tokenEpr", nil];
             NSLog(@"Validated Data %@ : ",dict);

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur De Connexion" message:@"l'application n'arrive pas à se connecter au serveur " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
            [alert show];

        }

    }

    - (void)dealloc {

    [altitude release];
    [longitude  release];
    [pictureLink release];
    //..... i release all variable
    [super dealloc];

}
```

This is the crash report:

```
Date/Time:       2011-12-15 23:21:55.719 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000b
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34499c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x308e3cd6 CFRetain + 62
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309940b8 __CFBasicHashStandardRetainValue + 8
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30995438 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308e3ff0 CFBasicHashAddValue + 276
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308e9d6c CFDictionaryCreate + 64
6   CoreFoundation                  0x308e977c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 1196
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30910890 -[NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 532
8   Myapp                           0x000488c4 -[FormViewController resultUpload:] (FormViewController.m:509)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x308edefc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
10  Myapp                           0x00026dbe -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2016)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x308edefc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
12  Foundation                      0x342427a2 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 262
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30959758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
17  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
18  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
19  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
20  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
21  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
22  Myapp                           0x000025a8 main (main.m:14)
23  Myapp                           0x00002550 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35590fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35261032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3526203a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x352615ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35f5327e _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x341dd7f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558fc60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3095d8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc2c semaphore_signal_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558df92 semaphore_signal + 2
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356645f4 pthread_mutex_unlock + 188
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3449ae2c objc_sync_exit + 44
4   Foundation                      0x341bfb7a -[NSThread _nq:] + 586
5   Foundation                      0x341bf7ec -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 724
6   Foundation                      0x341bf2e6 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 94
7   Myapp                           0x00026d0a -[ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2008)
8   Myapp                           0x0002e464 -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamComplete] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:3503)
9   Myapp                           0x0002bfa2 -[ASIHTTPRequest handleNetworkEvent:] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:3187)
10  Myapp                           0x0001baa2 ReadStreamClientCallBack (ASIHTTPRequest.m:54)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x308ffa1a _signalEventSync + 70
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30900626 _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 198
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30959758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3092d6d2 CFRunLoopRun + 42
18  Myapp                           0x00035cba +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4789)
19  Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
20  Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
22  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x1fdd8e10    r1: 0x312bd814      r2: 0x00000003      r3: 0x34a80c89
    r4: 0x00000003    r5: 0x3e7d62b4      r6: 0x00000020      r7: 0x2feed640
    r8: 0x00000008    r9: 0x2feed68c     r10: 0x00152d84     r11: 0x2feed6dc
    ip: 0x00000008    sp: 0x2feed628      lr: 0x30ecacdd      pc: 0x34a80c98
  cpsr: 0x000f0030

Binary Images:
   0xf0000 -   0x147fff +Myapp armv7  <5cac5a4eefa73eee9dd22e1ee04c20ca> /var/mobile/Applications/11660961-0E37-4121-A8A5-5EE99EFB342A/Myapp.app/Myapp
  0x192000 -   0x192fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <4070bd34b2c273416bcec248fd8b873d> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
  0x1c7000 -   0x1c8fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <ff6a576a67626b81229111c8c4169d09> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
 0x1270000 -  0x1295fff +Activator.dylib armv6  <a930347f472e332ba6a2f6809f12e335> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
 0x12a6000 -  0x12aafff +IntelliStatusIconsView.dylib armv6  <915699e8cb5c1a129984cec679515c50> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IntelliStatusIconsView.dylib
 0x12b4000 -  0x12b5fff +sandcastleclient.dylib armv6  <d138ce2db8b033aba6119acf3d561535> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib
 0x12b8000 -  0x12bbfff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  <5f24c4f6863b75d701ee663ed761c423> /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
0x2feef000 - 0x2ff14fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x305ec000 - 0x30615fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30616000 - 0x3064dfff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3064e000 - 0x3064ffff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x306ac000 - 0x306acfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x307aa000 - 0x3083ffff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3084c000 - 0x30858fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x309b7000 - 0x309b9fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x309ba000 - 0x30ad4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30ad9000 - 0x30aeffff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30c7d000 - 0x30c84fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30c91000 - 0x30c91fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30cce000 - 0x30d0bfff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30ec9000 - 0x30faefff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30fc9000 - 0x31356fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31377000 - 0x31464fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x31465000 - 0x31466fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31477000 - 0x31480fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x314d1000 - 0x314d3fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x314d4000 - 0x31525fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3153f000 - 0x31546fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3158b000 - 0x31590fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x315cb000 - 0x315d6fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31747000 - 0x31747fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31748000 - 0x31749fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3174a000 - 0x3176afff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31777000 - 0x317b9fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31d8c000 - 0x31dc4fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31e05000 - 0x31e41fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x31e6c000 - 0x338bafff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x33a07000 - 0x33a0cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33a0d000 - 0x33a16fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33b24000 - 0x33b6afff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33b6b000 - 0x33b77fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33c4c000 - 0x33c4efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33c4f000 - 0x33c54fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33d40000 - 0x33d44fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33e7a000 - 0x33e7efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33e80000 - 0x33f31fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33f32000 - 0x33f3ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34018000 - 0x3401efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x342f9000 - 0x342fafff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34367000 - 0x3436afff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3436b000 - 0x34380fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34587000 - 0x3458afff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3458b000 - 0x345d9fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x3468b000 - 0x346eafff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3479a000 - 0x348b9fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34986000 - 0x34a35fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34a36000 - 0x34a7cfff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34a7e000 - 0x34b42fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34d28000 - 0x34d5bfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34d5c000 - 0x34d63fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34d66000 - 0x34e87fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34ec8000 - 0x351b5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x351e1000 - 0x35216fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35217000 - 0x352d6fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x352d7000 - 0x352f0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35411000 - 0x35565fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35606000 - 0x35607fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3560c000 - 0x356b5fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x356e0000 - 0x356e5fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x357d3000 - 0x357f0fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3583d000 - 0x35841fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x35842000 - 0x3584ffff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x35880000 - 0x358bffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x358c0000 - 0x358c0fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3595f000 - 0x359cefff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x359cf000 - 0x35a24fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35a32000 - 0x35b5efff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x35b61000 - 0x35b64fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35b65000 - 0x35b7cfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35bcb000 - 0x35c15fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35c16000 - 0x35c18fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35c1a000 - 0x35c9bfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35c9c000 - 0x35cd4fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35d9c000 - 0x35d9dfff  TextInput_fr armv7  <df896624a716399f877087d35f6c6d86> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_fr.bundle/TextInput_fr
0x36100000 - 0x36204fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36262000 - 0x36281fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36534000 - 0x36b3ffff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36b40000 - 0x36b46fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36c14000 - 0x36c43fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36c4d000 - 0x36c5bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36c6e000 - 0x36c73fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36d76000 - 0x36d76fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
```

Comment: I don't think it matters but could you reverse `retain,nonatomic` in your .h file to make it `nonatomic, retain`?  I always see things declared the latter way.  Also, if you still do get a crash, what happens when you make a copy of the three @properties (i.e. declare a local NSString and assign each property to that) and then put them into the dictionary?

Comment: did you check the value of altitude, longitude and pictureLink before allocating you dictionary? They might be NULL.

Comment: @Niko i check for altitude and longitude in -(IBAction) validate:(id)sender , and pro pictureLink , if([responseString isEqualToString:@"ok"]) , i thnk it can't be NULL. Michael, ok i will trie to reverse but i don't thonk it's a problem

Comment: ok, so I guess, what morningstar suggest is the right answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not assign properties directly unless you are very sure what you're doing. Use `self.`. One side effect is it will retain the value. Since you did not retain the value, it was getting deallocated and when you tried to use it later you got a crash.

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    self.altitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude];

}
```

Comment: It work perfect, thank you you saved my life. I should alwayse use self. for global variables ?